# javascriptでtextareaの中の高さを取得する方法

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

textareaではスクロールが有効になるため文字数が多いと、textarea自体の高さと、中身の高さが変わると思います。

この中身の高さを得る方法はありますか?

Comment: textareaに設定されているrowsとcolsと中身のテキストから（論理行数ではなくて）表示行数がわかるからそれに設定されてるフォントの高さを掛ける・とか。

Comment: `scrollHeight`で、「中身の高さ」は取得できそうです。

[javascript - What is offsetHeight, clientHeight, scrollHeight? - Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22675126/what-is-offsetheight-clientheight-scrollheight)

Answer (score 1):

```
$('textarea').scrollTop() + $('textarea').innerHeight()
```

とかですかね・・・

Answer (score 0):

[`Element.scrollHeight`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollHeight)で取得できます。

```js
var area = document.getElementById('area');
var contentHeight = area.scrollHeight;

alert('中身の高さは' + contentHeight + 'pxです。');

if (confirm('エレメントの高さを調整しますか？')) {
  area.style.height = contentHeight + 'px';
}
```

```html
<textarea id="area" style="width: 250px; height: 100px; overflow-y: scroll;">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus nisi sem, sodales ac dolor quis, elementum varius massa. Sed eget odio tincidunt, dignissim justo eget, tempus est. Cras imperdiet tempus metus a mattis. Nullam pretium ultricies sapien sit amet iaculis. Integer eget dignissim odio, non ullamcorper augue. Pellentesque a interdum sapien. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. In tortor risus, elementum non congue sed, blandit nec arcu. Nam laoreet tincidunt efficitur.
</textarea>
```